# How could changing the remote battery suddenly cause my garage door to behave erratically?

Tags: garage-door-opener

My garage door remote was behaving properly yesterday -- it had just gradually become a bit less sensitive (I had to press the button harder, from a closer distance), so figured it was time to replace the battery in the remote.

Since that replacement--the door has been only closing halfway, or closing all the way and then re-opening once it touches the ground. It has also become "supersensitive"-- opening when I barely touch it. I swear one time I didn't even breathe on it. What's happening? I'm now afraid to use it.

Comment: I doubt it is a remote issue probably some other issue like spiders building a web in front of the safety sensors, check them and wipe dust and webs off and the problems will go away unless other maintenance is needed but probably not the remote.

Comment: How old is it?  What era? Sounds like something that happened with one of my rentals.  When it was all said and done I realized the door opener was from the 1970’s and didn’t have modern safety sensors.  It’s amazing the remote even survived, but the prior owner had lived there over 50 years.

Comment: Turned out it was related to the remote--I pressed it really hard in frustration, the casing clicked into place, and it began to work normally. Although I would expect an errant battery connection to result in no action, rather than erratic action. I'm grateful for your responses though, because they made me aware that older garage doors (like mine) lack modern safety sensors.